# Adding array in php and sort it

Tags: php, arrays

how to add array to be like this in php?

before:

```
'a' => 3, 'b' => 9
```

after:

```
'a' => 3, 'b' => 9, 'c' => 7, 'd' => 1
```

and sorting it with ascending

```
'd' => 1, 'a' => 3, 'c' => 7, 'b' => 9
```

Comment: Without knowing where does the added data comes from it is difficult to help you. For sorting: [How can I sort arrays and data in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/how-can-i-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you would have the first array and the second like this:

```
$firstArray = ['a' => 3, 'b' => 9];
$secondArray = ['c' => 7, 'd' => 1];
```

PHP allows you to concatenate the results by using the plus symbol **+**:

```
$test = $firstArray + $secondArray;
//$test = [
//    'a' => 3,
//    'b' => 9,
//    'c' => 7,
//    'd' => 1,
//];
```

And after that, to sort by values:

```
asort($test);
//$test = [
//    'd' => 1,
//    'a' => 3,
//    'c' => 7,
//    'b' => 9,
//];
```